# Youtube liveStreams insert getting error since Oct 1st 2020

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

Since Oct 1st we are getting error to create liveStreams insert... Broadcast creates fine, but when arrives in liveStreams getting this error:

```
"{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 500,\n    \"message\": \"Internal error encountered.\",\n    \"errors\": [\n      {\n        \"message\": \"Internal error encountered.\",\n        \"domain\": \"global\",\n        \"reason\": \"backendError\"\n      }\n    ],\n    \"status\": \"INTERNAL\"\n  }\n}\n""
```

Our code is the default one:

```
        $streamSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStreamSnippet();
        $streamSnippet->setTitle('New Stream');

        // Create an object for content distribution network details for the live
        // stream and specify the stream's format and ingestion type.
        $cdn = new Google_Service_YouTube_CdnSettings();
        $cdn->setFormat("720p"); //1080p
        $cdn->setIngestionType('rtmp');

        // Create the API request that inserts the liveStream resource.
        $streamInsert = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStream();
        $streamInsert->setSnippet($streamSnippet);
        $streamInsert->setCdn($cdn);
        $streamInsert->setKind('youtube#liveStream');

        // Execute the request and return an object that contains information
        // about the new stream.
        $streamsResponse = $youtube->liveStreams->insert('snippet,cdn', $streamInsert, array());
```

And our PHP Lib Version is the 'dev-master' one... I also tried with older one like 2.4.0 and nothing... same error.

Any idea Google Team or anybody?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

```
$cdn->setFormat("720p");
```

Not longer supported.

Changed to:

```
$cdn->setFrameRate("30fps");
$cdn->setResolution("720p");
```

And worked.